# Huawei G8 (GX8) big problem (strange)

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, fastboot

<sup>first of all sorry for my English. I'm from Bulgaria and second this is my first time ever to do this so please excuse me if i'm doing something wrong.</sup>

I have a Huawei G8 (Rio L01). I tried to install another ROM. I have done it so many times with 30+ different Samsung phone. So I downloaded "custom rom 6.0.1" for Huawei L01. My device is rooted so I installed the latest TWRP and got a problem: I got stuck in Recovery Mode.

I had this problem a couple of years ago. I Installed older TWRP and problem solved. So I made a Factory reset, wiped and all I should do, then installed the rom, restarted the phone and boot. I got it to the screen where u choose LANGUAGE (the first screen after boot) and the moment I choose language my phone went crazy: blue, green, yellow absolutely every color on the display and flashing o.O I turned off the phone and booted it up again and got to that language choose screen and didn't press anything and same thing. I tried 10+ times and same thing: display goes crazy.

I can't go to RECOVERY MODE – only can go to that "FASTBOOT AND RESCUE MODE" . Please help! I can upload pictures if needed.

P.S. it is the bigger version - 3GB RAM, 32GB ROM, dual sim if important.